# CountIf Comparing Dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

My CountIf function is straight just not working, and I'm curious what I've done wrong. It only seems to output 1 or 0, and bizarrely is doing so differently depending on where in the sheet I put the data.

[image]

[image]

What's going on with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) can compare a range to a value, and it returns a scalar. It **can** compare a range to a range, but in that case it returns an array instead, so you should sum up those values with [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(G2:G16,H2:H16))
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(C10:C24,D10:D24))
```

You could also use a CSE formula (CSE means you have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>):

```
=COUNT(IF(G2:G16=H2:H16,1,""))
=COUNT(IF(C10:C24=D10:D24,1,""))
```

This also counts blank cells when compared to other blank cells, so it might not be what you want.

**Update:** I'd like to include [Bandersnatch](https://superuser.com/users/740226/bandersnatch)'s solution that separately counts the blanks and subtracts them from the total: `=COUNT(IF(G2:G16=H2:H16,1,""))-SUM((G2:G16="")*(H2:H16=""))`.

See a similar problem solved [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/512062-countif-using-range-comparison.html) and [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-total-matches-in-two-ranges).

Comment: Great answer.  Using SUMPRODUCT() is the simple and elegant solution.  But if for some reason you need to use the array formula, this modification will subtract out the blanks. `=COUNT(IF(G2:G16=H2:H16,1,""))-SUM((G2:G16="")*(H2:H16=""))`